# How to construct multible rules for replacement at once?

Tags: replacement, rule

After generating a list for which I used //N, I want to replace some values with the exact one.

What I had in mind is to generate something like:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -3, -4} /. {x_ /; x < 0 -> n, x > 0 -> p}
```

where the outcome is:`{p, p, p, p, n, n, n, n}`

My problem here is that my output prioritizes `/;` first and doesn't set `d=5` and the `i` only gets distributed in the last omega (`-> \[Omega][d]^(i)`):

```
%/.Module[{d = 5},
Table[x_ /; Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] - 10^(-5) < 
Im[x] < Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] + 10^(-5) -> \[Omega][
 d]^(i), {i, 0, 4}]]
```

Output:

```
{x$_ /; Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d$472152]^i]]] - 1/10^5 <
Im[x$] < Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d$472152]^i]]] + 1/10^5 -> 1,...,...}
```

My noobish attempt was:

```
%/.Module[{d = 5}, ("x_/;") /@
Table[Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] - 10^(-5) < x_ /; 
Im[x] < Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] + 10^(-5) -> \[Omega][
 d]^(i), {i, 0, 4}]]
```

Output here:
without `%/.`

```
{"x_ /;"[-(1/100000) < Im[x] < 0 -> 1],...,...}
```

with `%/.`

Syntax error:

....is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, \
and so cannot be used for replacing.

Thanks for help beforehand!

Comment: try `Block[{d = 5}, 
 Table[With[{i = i}, 
   x_ /; Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] - 10^(-5) < Im[x] < 
      Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]] + 10^(-5)] -> \[Omega][d]^(i)], {i, 
   0, 4}]]`?

Comment: your code as no problems, but still doesn't replaces my stuff. Maybe problems with my stuff.. I will tell if it's a problem from the code or my own a little later, THANKS

Comment: ah, the promblem is that `Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^0]]]` doens\t get evaluated: The Output is: `{x$_ /; Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^0]]] - 1/10^10 < Im[x$] < 
    Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^0]] + 1/10^10] -> 1,...,..}`

Comment: that means `d` wasn't `5`, omega is had still `d` inside

Comment: `% /. Table[
  With[{i = i, d = 5}, 
   x_ /; Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] - 10^(-3) < Im[x] < 
      Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] + 10^(-3) -> \[Omega][d]^(i)], {i, 
   0, 4}]` WORKS! THANKS, didn't know that `With[ ]` existed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks kglr!
Gave me the right tools to solve this!

The answer:

```
% /. Table[ With[{i = i, d = 5}, x_ /; Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] - 10^(-3) <
Im[x] < Im[Chop[N[\[Omega][d]^(i)]]] + 10^(-3) -> \[Omega][d]^(i)], {i, 0, 4}]
```